# Set a select value with jQuery not working

Tags: jquery

All,
I have the following bit of HTML code for a select box:

```
<select name="display_dj_entries" id="display_dj_entries">
<option value="original">Select a DJ</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to set this value back to the original value when another select box is changed on my page. I have the following jQuery to do this:

```
jQuery(document).on('change','#display_gear_entries',function(event){
    var selected_value = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery("#display_dj_entries option[value='original']").attr("selected", "selected");
});
```

It isn't setting the value back to the original value but instead leaving it set to the value of 1. What am I doing wrong on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery("#display_dj_entries").prop("selectedIndex", 0);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8QFPp/2/)**

Comment: `selectedIndex` is a property of the `select` element, not the `option`.

Answer (score 0):

Or even shorter:

> $('#display_dj_entries').val('original');

This assumes the value attribute is 'original' for unselected option.